# Using amazon SNS to call two nodes of the same application

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

We need to clean the cache of an application that is deployed in a two different nodes.

Our problem : We have a http servlet endpoint to clean the cache, however, it only cleans the cache from one node, but not from the other, and that leads to incoherences.

As we host the application on amazon, we would like to use SNS to publish to a topic and that both nodes get notified in order to clean their caches.

How can we achieve this? Using SNS with an SQS queue is not an option as we don't want to poll the queue, the call to the servlets endpoints needs to be done inmediatly.

Answer (score 1):

SNS supports http endpoints as subscribers.

So, you can directly subscribe the http endpoints as subscribers to SNS. The notification will go immediately.

You don't need SQS in between.